# vb.net show progress bar while program take some time to complete

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

i have a query like these

```
if ..... then

getcmd= "insert into node(...) select ..."
CMD = New MySqlCommand(getcmd, conn.connect)
CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
CMD.Connection.Close()

elseif ... then
getcmd= "insert into node(...) select ..."
CMD = New MySqlCommand(getcmd, conn.connect)
CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
CMD.Connection.Close()

else
getcmd= "insert into node(...) select ..."
CMD = New MySqlCommand(getcmd, conn.connect)
CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
CMD.Connection.Close()

end if
```

the problem is when i compile this code, it took some time to complete.. it's about 10-60seconds.. it varies depend on the input of user.. it proccess a huge data around 3,8k records which causing the compiler need some time to complete

now i need a simple progress bar that could show up while the program running

my requirement is so that the user know that the program is running in progress NOT HANGS

only a simple progress bar is fine, don't need a function to count estimated time to complete..

could you show me the simplest way to do this.. thanks before

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to count estimated completion time, simply display indeterminate progress bar by setting `Style` property of progress bar to `ProgressBarStyle.Marquee`.

```
'at the beginning, before entering code blocks that needs some time to complete
ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
......
......
'after execution completed
ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks
```

In addition to `Style`, you may also want to change `Visible` property to hide/show the progress bar.